# XPath query on node-set working like a SQL where in

Tags: sql, xml, xpath, reference, nodes

a sample of xml document:

```
  <xml>
    <list>
      <item refid="1" />
      <item refid="3" />
    </list>
    <catalogue>
      <model id="1"><details /></model>
      <model id="2"><details /></model>
      <model id="3"><details /></model>
    </catalogue>
  </xml>
```

I'd like to query something like //model[ @id = (//item/@refid) ] 
to obtain all "model" having a referenced id in "list"

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for detailed explanation, analysis and optimized solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'd like to query something like
>   //model[ @id = (//item/@refid) ] to
>   obtain all "model" having a referenced
>   id in "list"

**The main problem here is your lack of confidence** and not actually running an XPath engine to evaluate the expressions you've come up with.

If you evaluate the XPath expression you proposed:

```
//model[ @id = (//item/@refid) ]
```

You'll see that it selects exactly the (two) `model` elements, whose `id` attributes are referenced by the `refid` attributes of `item` elements that are children of `list`.

@Jörn-Horstmann in his answer already explained why you get these results.

**A minor remark is to generally avoid using the `//` abbreviation**. It causes the whole document to be scanned and is very inefficient. In this case I would use the equivalent but probably faster to evaluate XPath expression:

```
/*/catalogue/model[@id = /*/list/item/@refid]
```

Comment: Thanks, your conclusion is exactly what I was looking for, evaluating an alternative xpath operation.

Answer (score 2):

Your xpath expression should already return exactly what you want. Quoting from http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#booleans, 5th paragraph:

> If one object to be compared is a node-set and the other is a string, then the comparison will be true if and only if there is a node in the node-set such that the result of performing the comparison on the string-value of the node and the other string is true